# I just finished fixing a mysql admin base and getting info page, when it redirects to the login page it gives me a parse error on line 33

Tags: mysql, parsing

```
33.}if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
34.function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue 35.= "") 
36.{
37.  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
38.    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
39.  }
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code please?